# How can we delete rows from a join table by using ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
create_table "tags_pages", :id => false do |t|

  t.integer "tag_id", "page_id"

end

add_index "tags_pages", "tag_id"
add_index "tags_pages", "page_id"
```

How activerecord works on this table ? I want to insert and delete new rows. Sorry if it is a noob question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's suppose you have one page and one tag.

```
# This will add a "tags_pages" entry, linking one page to one tag
page.tags << tag

# This will delete the appropriate "tags_pages" entry
page.tags.delete(tag)
```

You can also delete all the tags linked to one page with the `clear` method.

```
page.tags.clear
```